# Handling Event without use of Button?

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2012, secondary-live-tile

I just created an Button in xaml so, it created an event for handling the button click.
I want to call the contents inside the event handler as a function. So, that i can call in some other place to satisfy my needs.

Currently i am working in Live tiles. examples that i got are all in the form of button click event to trigger the flip and cycle tiles.

I want to call those into function to make it work.

Or else any one give the example of Lives tiles from the beginning to end

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking us. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So move the code in the button click handler to its own method!  The button click handler will then just call that method.  Now you can either click the button or call that method directly from somewhere else...